# Does the second derivative commute with inversion?

Tags: calculus, operator-theory

Say you have the second derivative operator  $D=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ and the inversion operator $I$, such that $If(x)=f(-x)$. According to my calculations, $Dg(x)=g^{''}(x)$ and $IDg(x)=g^{''}(-x)$. However, $Ig(x)=g(-x)=g(h(x))$, where $h(x)=-x$. Therefore, $\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{dh}{dx}\frac{d}{dh}=-\frac{d}{dh}$ and $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}=-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dh}=\frac{d}{dh}\frac{d}{dh}=\frac{d^2}{dh^2}$. So, $DIg(x)=\frac{d^2}{dh^2}g(h(x))=g^{''}(x)$ and the two operators do not in general commute.

Is deduction correct?

Answer (score 4):

As you wrote, let $h(x)=-x$, so that $If=f\circ h.$ Then,

$(DI)(f)=(f\circ h)'=h'\times(f'\circ h)=-(ID)(f),$ so
$$DI=-ID,$$
hence (by induction)
$$D^nI=(-1)^nID^n$$
(in particular, $D^2I=ID^2$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be the derivative operator. In the first case we have:
$$(D^2I)(f(x)) = D^2(f(-x)) = D(-f'(-x)) = f''(-x)$$
And the second case:
$$(ID^2)(f(x)) = I(f''(x)) =f''(-x)$$ So we have $$(D^2I)(f(x)) = (ID^2)(f(x))$$
Note that the chain rule is as follows:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(u(x)) = u'(x)\times f'(u(x))$$

Comment: OK, I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: @user1524841 You're welcome. Note that you can mark an answer if it answers your question.